# 'In the Sangrur District of Punjab'.- is correct or 'In Sangrur District of Punjab'.-is correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I have a doubt regarding the usage of article in the sentence given in the title.

Comment: A district is part of a country or region, so it's OK to use 'the' of a named district in the same way as you would say 'in the northern part of Punjab'.

Comment: @Edwin This question is not in any way a duplicate of that one. The definite article here is an entirely different and unrelated phenomenon.

Comment: @Janus It is related in that usage is idiosyncratic. Examples occur online of both "in Al-Mada'in District" and "in the Al-Mada'in District". "∅ Bradford district" and "the Bradford district". "∅ Midtown District, Reno" and "the Midtown District, Reno" etc etc.  "The District of Columbia" is fixed, though the 'the' may be deleted in less formal writing. The underlying questions in both strings are 'Is the article part of the compound / close collocation, and is it optional?' Colin Fine's answer addresses this.

Comment: In what context? The anarthrous form is acceptable in certain contexts.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the following are correct:

in Sangrur District

in the district of Sangrur

in the Sangrur D/district of Punjab

Comment: Based on what? When? How do we know which one is right when and where? Are they interchangeable? If not, what is the rule for choosing one or the other?